# Excel date formula - if between date x and date y

Tags: excel

I have 3 date buckets.

1. 21.01.2014 to 21.01.2017
2. 22.01.2017 to 22.01.2022
3. 23.01.2022 +

I have a list of dates and wish to have A formula that identifies which date bucket that date is and return the corresponding number 1,2 or 3. So 26.04.2019 would return a 2 as per above. Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use following formula:

```
=MATCH(TEXT(A1, "dd.mm.yyyy"),{"21.01.2014","22.01.2017","23.01.2022"},1)
```

or (depends on your local settings)

```
=MATCH(TEXT(A1, "dd.mm.yyyy"),{"21.01.2014";"22.01.2017";"23.01.2022"},1)
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for `MATCH` approach but I would assume these are valid dates in which case with start dates of each "bucket" in Z1:Z3 it would be sufficient to use `=MATCH(A1,$Z$1:$Z$3)`

Comment: Thank you! You're right, if OP can use the extra cells for baskets, your formula is better suited. About `Text(...)` - when I use array in formula like `{"21.01.2014";"22.01.2017";"23.01.2022"}`, my dates stores like text, and I have to use `Text(...)`, because my date from `A1` converts to sth like this `44576`